# Why won't Maple 15 graph modulo?

Tags: graph, modulo, maple

I am trying to graph the function f(x) = x mod 7
The graph should look like a bunch of spiked lines.  Instead it is graphing a straight line f(x) = x
What am I doing wrong?  This seems so basic.  Is Maple Bugged?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The f you define is a procedure in terms of x. When maple gets `plot(f(x),x=1..10)`, it first tries to evaluate f without filling in the numeric values of x. Your solution of `plot(f,1..10)` is the correct way to plot a procedure, the first one is to plot a general formula. In `plot(f,1..10)` Maple detects that you're plotting a procedure and fills in x correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but this syntax was what was needed:

> plot(f, 1 .. 10)